# Simplify if statements, Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to simplify the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        /* 1 */if (c2 - c1 == 0) {
            /* 2 */if (c1 != c3) {
                c3 += c1;
                /* 4 */System.out.println(c3);
                /* 5 */c3 *= c2;
                /* 6 */}
        }

        /* 7 */if (c1 == c3)
            /* 8 */if (c1 - c2 == 0)
            /* 9 */{
                c3 += c1;
                /* 10 */System.out.println(c3);
                /* 11 */c3 *= c1;
                /* 12 */if (c1 < c2)
                    c2 += 7;
                /* 13 */else
                    c2 += 5;
                /* 14 */}

        /* 15 */System.out.println(c1 + c2 + c3);
    }
```

First `c2 - c1 == 0` is the same as `c2 == c1` and `c1 - c2 == 0` is the same is as `c1 == c2`. Besides I can remove the `if (c1 < c2)` and keep the content of the else statement.

The result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        /* 1 */if (c1 == c2) {
            /* 2 */if (c1 != c3) {
                c3 += c1;
                /* 4 */System.out.println(c3);
                /* 5 */c3 *= c2;
                /* 6 */}
        }

        /* 7 */if (c1 == c3)
            /* 8 */if (c1 == c2)
            /* 9 */{
                c3 += c1;
                /* 10 */System.out.println(c3);
                /* 11 */c3 *= c1;

                    c2 += 5;
                /* 14 */}

        System.out.println(c1 + c2 + c3);
    }
```

My question is what could be simplified now? If the inner if would be outside I could simplify the if's. What do you think?

Comment: Just curious; what is this for?

Comment: *"What do you think?"* I think that with the indentation and line number comments, that code is nearly unreadable and probably preventing your getting answers to this question. Make the code readable (with regular indentation and the numbers to the far right) and you may have more luck.

Comment: @Evan: Yeah, looks like homework or a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning: I've assumed your 2nd version of the code to be correct, i.e. that your initial simplication is correct.

The mess of `if` statements can be simplified down to:

```
if (c1 == c2) {
  c3 += c1;
  System.out.println(c3);
  if (c1 != c3) {
    c3 *= c2;
  } else {
    c2 += 5;
    c3 *= c1;
  }
}
```

Using your `/* line numbers /*` as reference point, this is what I simplified:

- Factor out the common condition in 1 and 8
- Factor out the common code around 4 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

Try using some conditional operators in your ifs, there's no reason to nest them if you can do an `&&`.

```
if (c1 == c2 && c1 != c3) {
    ...
}

if (c1 == c2 && c2 == c3) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Probably because someone doesn't understand what conditional operators are. :/

Comment: @marcog Possibly, although a further simplification, (i.e. your answer) doesn't need them, so my answer's probably moot. :)

Comment: Your point is still valid and OP will likely learn something from it. So keep it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    if(c1 == c2)
    {
        c3 += c1;
        System.out.println(c3);

        if(c1 == c3)
        {
            c3 *= c1;
            c2 += 5;
        }
        else
        {
            c3 *= c2;
        }       
    }
    System.out.println(c1 + c2 + c3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

if (c2 == c1) 
    {  
        if(c1!= c3)
        {
            c3 += c1;
            System.out.println(c3);
            c3 *= c2;
        } 
        else {
            c3 += c1;
            System.out.println(c3);
            c3 *= c1;
            c2 += 5;
        }
    }
System.out.println(c1 + c2 + c3);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot factor out the if statements. they executed sequentially and the first changes the values for the second. The result changes.